# How to write multiple instruction in SML's definition of a function

Tags: function, sml, towers-of-hanoi

I want to run a Hanoi Algorithm via SML so i used the following C-like code:

```
fun Hanoi 1 source dest by = print ("Move the plate from"^source^"to"^dest^"/n")
| n source dest by = Hanoi n-1 source by dest 
    print ("Move the plate from"^^source^^"to"^^dest^^"/n")
    Hanoi n-1 by dest source
```

It's something wrong with this code. My guess is that i am not writing properly the n case of the algorithm because of the multiple instructions that it has.
In any case i would really appreciate your help. 
If you can, understand that i am a totally amateur coder in ML, which means i have very little knowledge of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "instructions" in ML, only expressions. The semicolon operator allows evaluating several expressions in sequence. This should compile:

```
fun hanoi 1 source dest by =
    print ("Move the plate from"^source^"to"^dest^"/n")
  | hanoi n source dest by =
    (hanoi (n-1) source by dest;
     print ("Move the plate from"^source^"to"^dest^"/n");
     hanoi (n-1) by dest source)
```

Note that you need to parenthesise the use of semicolon. You also need parens around the `n-1`, because infix operators have lower precedence than function application.